# JS | Object comparison with Object.compare

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, compare

I am using `underscore` in my AngularJS application. I want to compare deep object values with ES6 Compare method.

Here is the current code:

```
$scope.$watch(
    () => ctrl.parameters,
    (newValue, oldValue) => {
      if (newValue && newValue.table) {
        if (!oldValue || newValue.type === oldValue.type) {
          if (
            oldValue &&
            oldValue.partition &&
            !_.isEqual(newValue.partition, oldValue.partition) // The line 
            // I want to change
          ) {
             ...some_code
          } else {
            ...someMoreCode
          }
        }
      }
    },
    true
  );
```

This is how I used to compare:

```
$scope.$watch(
    () => ctrl.parameters,
    (newValue, oldValue) => {
      if (newValue && newValue.table) {
        if (!oldValue || newValue.type === oldValue.type) {
          if (
            oldValue &&
            oldValue.partition &&
           !Object.compare(newValue.partition, oldValue.partition) // The 
           // line I want to change
          ) {
             ...some_code
          } else {
            ...someMoreCode
          }
        }
      }
    },
    true
  );
```

But I get the following error, `Object.compare is not a function`. What am I doing wrong? Thank you..

Comment: Well, `Object.compare` is not a function. It doesn't exist in either ES6 or elsewhere.

Comment: *"But I get the following error, Object.compare is not a function. What am I doing wrong?"* JavaScript has no `compare` function on `Object`. In fact, there's no `compare` function anywhere in the JavaScript standard library (up to and including ES2019), nor am I aware of any [active proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposals) for one. (There's `localeCompare` on `String`, but that's about it.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder just to add here, there exists an `Object.is` function but it basically does a `===` between two values, doesn't do deep equality in any fashion. So, I'm not sure what OP is trying to use here.

Comment: @VLAZ - Yeah, although `Object` was a bizarre place for them to put that function, as it has nothing to do with comparing objects.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't disagree there. I suspect it was probably fashioning after [`Object#equals` in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: @VLAZ - I wouldn't have thought so. `Object#equals` in Java **is** about comparing objects. I think the idea was most likely to avoid any more global identifiers (which I know is explicitly important to TC39) and making `Object` a dumping ground for utility features. I would have argued for `Reflect`, but there's a group at TC39 who want `Reflect` to have exactly the methods necessary for proxy traps and nothing more (or less). ANYway... :-)